# What is a good design pattern for multi-mode software?

Tags: design-patterns

I will explain my question by way of example, but I'd love a general solution.

I am writing a JavaScript application that needs to function differently depending on its run-time context. To handle this, I have have done the following. (1) At the beginning of the program, I set two context variables—let's say `is_foo` and `is_bar`, which can't both be true. Then (2) throughout the code, I check these variables whenever I need to account for the context:

```
if (is_foo) {
    app.do_something(is_foo_config);
} else if (is_bar) {
    app.do_something(is_bar_config);
}
```

Are there any good design patterns or best practices for designing a program that has a "mode" with related configurations?

Comment: Is it possible for the mode to change while the application is running, or is it set once on startup?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, it is set once at startup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, instead of setting a flag, you want to use polymorphism to choose between different implementations.  In other words, instead of checking `is_foo` all over the place, do it once at the start, like:

```js
if (is_foo) {
  app = new FooApp();
} else {
  app = new BarApp();
}
```

Alternately, if only the config is different, do something like this at the start:

```js
if (is_foo) {
  config = is_foo_config;
} else {
  config = is_bar_config;
}
```

This lets you later just do:

```js
app.do_something(config);
```

Basically, by doing the `if` statement once, you minimize the possibility of accidentally forgetting to do it at some later point, and usually also eliminates a lot of repetition.

Answer (score 12):

Since the mode is selected at startup<sup>1</sup> the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) would work.

Related is the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ReplaceConditionalWithPolymorphism) (also [here](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)) and [Replace Type Code with State/Strategy](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-type-code-with-state-strategy) refactoring.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> If the mode were changing during the course of execution, then the [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) would be called for.  It's similar to the Strategy pattern and has similar inner workings.